# $f(x)<+\infty$ ($x\to\infty$) $ \Rightarrow$ there exists {$x_n$}$ \subset \mathbb{R} $ s.t. $x_n\to\infty$ and $ x_n f'(x_n)\to0 $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that

$f(x)$ is $C^1$ monotone increasing function on $[0,\infty)$ ,then

$f(x)<+\infty$ ($x\to\infty$) $ \Rightarrow$ there exists {$x_n$}$ \subset \mathbb{R} $ s.t. $x_n\to\infty$ and  $ x_n f'(x_n)\to0 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $l=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)<\infty$. We construct a sequence
$(x_{n})$ recursively as follow. Choose $x_{1}\in[0,\infty)$ arbitrarily.
Suppose that $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n-1}$ have been chosen such that
$x_{k}-x_{k-1}\geq1$ for $k=2,3,\ldots,n-1$. For $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{4n}$,
there exists $X>x_{n-1}+1$ such that $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$ whenever
$x\in[X,\infty)$. In particluar, $|f(2X)-f(X)|\leq|f(2X)-l|+|l-f(X)|<2\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2n}$.
By mean-value theorem, there exists $x_{n}\in(X,2X)$ such that $f(2X)-f(X) = f'(x_n)(2X-X)$. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \frac{1}{2n}\\
 & > & f(2X)-f(X)\\
 & = & f'(x_{n})(2X-X)\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2}(2X)f'(x_{n})\\
 & \geq & \frac{1}{2}x_{n}f'(x_{n})
\end{eqnarray*}
(observe that since $f$ is increasing, $f'\geq0$). Hence, $x_{n}f'(x_{n})<\frac{1}{n}.$

By recursion, we obtain a sequence $(x_{n})$ such that $x_{n}-x_{n-1}\geq1$
and $x_{n}f'(x_{n})<\frac{1}{n}$ for $n=2,3,\ldots$. In particular,
$x_{n}\rightarrow\infty$ and $x_{n}f'(x_{n})\rightarrow0$.